# javascript: How to make a module to behave like and object and a function simultaneously?

Tags: closures, javascript, prototype-programming, scoping

I'm trying to build myself a little helper library. first, for learning purposes, then that later I can extend it so it may come in handy in projects.

I understand somewhat the prototype referencing, closures, and scoping. I also intentionally made it using modular pattern so my `toolbox` is not polluting the global namespace. 
I also know we may assign prototypes to constructor functions, so the constructed Objects will hold those methods.

Here's the content of `toolbox.js`

```
(function (window) { 
var toolbox = (function () { 
    var toolbox = function(it){
            return new pick(it);
    }
    var pick = function (it){
        var craft = document.getElementsByTagName(it);
        craft = Array.prototype.slice.call(craft, 0);
        return Array.prototype.push.apply(this, craft);
    }

    pick.prototype = toolbox.prototype = {
        raw: function(){
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(this, 0);
        }, 
        tell: function(secret){
            return secret;
        }
    }

    return toolbox;
}());
window.toolbox = toolbox;
})(window);
```

and calling the `toolbox`:

```
toolbox("div"); //returns the desired object with the div collection
toolbox("div").raw(); //returns a raw array with the divs
toolbox().tell("A secret"); //returns "A secret"
toolbox.tell("It's a secret"); //type error: the function has no method like tell (like hell it does...should)
```

but modifying the above code like this:

```
var toolbox = (function () { 
    var toolbox = function(it){
    return new pick(it);
}
     ...
    toolbox.tell(secret){ return secret }
return toolbox;
}());
```

will work.

So my question is why `toolbox.prototype = {}`  doesn't do the trick, while `pick.prototype = {}` will make `pick` inherit the defined methods?

I'd like to achieve both `toolbox.tell("something");` and `toolbox("div").raw();` to be possible without having to resolve directly prototyping the method into the modul.

Please help! I've been googling for days to learn these, and I'm stuck now. Your help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Here's how jQuery does this in a nutshell:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    var jQuery = (function() {
        // Define a local copy of jQuery
        var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
                // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
                return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
            }   

        jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
            constructor: jQuery,
            init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
                //init stuff
            }
        };

        // Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
        jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;

        jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {
            //extend stuff
        };

        jQuery.extend({
            //extend stuff
        });

    // Expose jQuery to the global object
    return jQuery;

    })();
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);
```

Comment: The `prototype` property is only "applied" in a Constructor (when it is made the `[[prototype]]` of the new object). There is no Constructor for `toolbox` here. Consider a manual copy of the properties: `toolbox.tell = toolbox().tell`, etc

Comment: May want to see how jQuery does this.

Comment: @pst
thanks for the correction, I was suspicious the problem is toolbox has no Constructor. However I'm looking for a solution to make it automatic. yes. like jQuery. I may Edit my question to add a jQuery example.

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the jQuery example. hundreds of lines of code is confusing to compress. but it is a proper example now.

Comment: I don't understand how any of your calls to toolbox() work at all, because all of your toolbox.js code is wrapped in an anonymous self-executing function (yes - I know 'self-executing' is not an entirely accurate description but most people know what is meant), so doesn't that mean that things declared inside that function are hidden from code on the page that includes toolbox.js? Maybe I'm just tired.

Comment: @nnnnnn
yes, exactly, but that is why the very last `return toolbox;` is responsible to reveal only one global function, which is toolbox itself.

Comment: @tenshou - what? But that return is not in the outermost scope, and nothing makes it available outside the scope of the outside function. In your edited question with the JQuery extract, the last line of their anonymous function makes an object accessible in the global (or window) scope - something the toolbox.js code didn't do. So that clears up the confusion of my previous comment. I assume you were originally doing something like that in your code but didn't quite copy it all into your original question.

Comment: I feel ashamed of making such mistake. you are so right. I did forgot to copy it properly. However, I've been doing this all night, I'm also tired. i corrected the copy. now it includes `window.toolbox = toolbox;`

Comment: if I can vote this question down more than once i would. by definition all JS functions ARE objects. you should read a book.

Comment: maybe I should, but I think you missed the point of my question. see the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference when something is in a prototype and when it's on the object itself.

Consider the following example:

```
var foo = function() { return 'I am foo'; }

foo.prototype.lie = function() { return 'I am not foo'; }
foo.lie(); //error, lie does not exist in foo

var bar = new foo;
bar.lie(); //it works!
```

`prototype` is basically the mid-way between the parent and the child. The prototype has all what the parent has, plus what you appended to it - however, the parent does not have its own prototype. And, to be more confusing, if you assign stuff to the parent object and not to its prototype, the extra stuff won't get copied to the children. Weird, right?

To explain the last statement (using the previous example):

```
foo.makeAPoem = function() { return 'Roses are red, violets are blue, coffe milk eggs'; }
var bar = new foo;
foo.makeAPoem(); //works
bar.makeAPoem(); //nope!
```

It's exactly why you don't have `String.split` for example, but `'abcd'.split` - these methods exist in the prototype.

If you want to make something works in both the object and the prototype, assign it to both!

```
foo.jedi = foo.prototype.jedi = function() { return 'This is not the function you are looking for'; }
foo.jedi(); //works
bar.jedi(); //works!
```

So now, you can choose what gets inherited and what stays in the parent. If you want it only available to the parent, only append it to the parent. However, if you want it to only be available on the child (e.g. you don't have `jQuery.andSelf`, but you do have jQuery().andSelf) append it to the prototype. If you want both, append it to both.

Comment: Wwow, thank you! You explained it perfectly! This is what I've been missing :)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a power constructor (I'm not sure it's really called that way =)), something like:

```
var toolbox = (function(){
 // some private methods
   var test_1 = function(){ alert("test_1"); };
   var test_2 = function(){ alert("test_1"); };
 // return needed methods and props into the global namespace: 
   return {
    "test_1" : test_1,
    "test_2" : test_2
   }
})();

toolbox.test_1();
```

Comment: Power constructor. I like that! It resembles to the pattern they call 'revealing patter' which reveals only your selected methods in the `return{}`. Thanky, I'll look into it, you just gave me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that toolbox was never instantiated as a constructor like pick was. Simple solution.

Instead of

```
pick.prototype = toolbox.prototype = {
....
...
return toolbox;
```

use just

```
pick.prototype = {
....
....
for(var attr in pick.prototype) {
  toolbox[attr] = pick.prototype[i];
}
```

This will add the methods directly to toolbox

Comment: yyes, good insight! jQuery does this in a waay more sophisticated way with `jQuery.merge();`, which they (and plugin writers) use to extend the namespace. I think this completes what I need, thank you for you answer, wish I could upvote it!

Comment: I mean `jQuery.extend();`. Sorry. still, your idea is great, thank you!